# How to use Apache Tika to extract the "From", "To", and "Subject" fields by using Apache Metadata class?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I'm using the Apache  Tika library, specifically the Metadata class,  to 
extract the "From" ,  "To" , and "Subject" fields from an Outlook Exchange file (email file , i.e `.msg` files).

I know that I need to use the Metadata class, but I'm having a little trouble using it.

Here is my code so far :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
/* more tika imports */

public class ExtractFromEmail {

   public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException , SAXException {

    File file = new File("message_1980.msg");
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata tikaMetadata = new Metadata();
    Property prop = new Property("MESSAGE_FROM");
    String fromField = tikaMetadata.get(prop); //  USE THIS PATTERN
    InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(file, tikaMetadata);
    parser.parse(input, handler, tikaMetadata, new ParseContext());
    String other = tikaMetadata.MESSAGE_FROM ; 


     System.out.println(fromField);

    }

    }
```

I get following error when I run the code :

> ExtractFromEmail.java:30: error: no suitable constructor found for
>   Property(String)
>           Property prop = new Property("Message.MESSAGE_FROM");

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try this with tika-1.14:

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/unicode.msg");
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata tikaMetadata = new Metadata();
InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(file, tikaMetadata);
parser.parse(input, handler, tikaMetadata, new ParseContext());
String messageFrom = tikaMetadata.MESSAGE_FROM;
String fromField = tikaMetadata.get(messageFrom);
System.out.println(fromField);
```

and works. Your problem was that you tried to extract metadata before parsing the message. In addition I believe that the line `Property prop = new Property("MESSAGE_FROM");` was useless and incorrect.

Comment: Hi Nicomedes , I'm not sure why but this one still doesn't work  - it prints "null"

Comment: - Maybe it's a version-issue  ? i think I am using 1.14 Tika

Comment: Ok nevrmind , - I got this to work now - thanks a lot !